# Insert a json in redShift using query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to insert data into redshift table using this SQL query:

```
insert into temp(JSON)({"name":"abc","lname":"xyz"});
```

but it does not work, I get an error:

> Syntax error

Is there any way to insert json data into redshift using a query?

I want to insert a whole json object into query instead of passing key and values

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSON_PARSE('serialized_json') - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_PARSE.html

The JSON column should be of the SUPER data type - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html

```
INSERT INTO temp
  (JSON)
VALUES
  (JSON_PARSE('{"name":"abc","lname":"xyz"}'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply execute:

`insert into temp values('{"name":"abc","lname":"xyz"}');`

JSON as a datatype is not supported on Redshift - [**Amazon Redshift Documentation**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html)

Comment: Side-note. There are functions such as [`JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html) that can then use the JSON data stored in this way.

Comment: Update -> You can insert semi-structured data into redshift with the SUPER data type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html.